# Make current entry in argument list global accross different tabs

Tags: vim, neovim

I noticed that the current entry in the argument list is local to the tab. Is there any way I can make it global across all tabs.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate what I want:

First I open vim with: `vim foo.txt bar.txt`.

Running `:ar` shows `[foo.txt] bar.txt`, where the `[` and `]` denote the current entry in the arg list.

Then I open a new tab with `:tabnew` and move to the next entry in the arg list with `:next`.

Running `:ar` at this point shows: `foo.txt   [bar.txt]`.

If I go back to the first tab with `gt` and run `:ar`, I get `[foo.txt] bar.txt`, which shows that the current entry of the arg list in this tab was not updated by the `:next` command I ran from the second tab. I basically want to keep in sync the current entry in my arg list across all tabs. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> where the `[` and `]` denote the current entry in the arg list.

There is no "current entry in the arg list". The square brackets are meant to highlight the current file in the argument list (if it is in there), not show the current state of the argument list because there is no such thing.

> which shows that the current entry of the arg list in this tab was not updated by the `:next` command I ran from the second tab.

The `:next` command only edits the next file from the list. It doesn't advance a cursor somewhere or updates anything because there is nothing to update.

The argument list is stateless. If you want a stateful argument list you will have to write it all by yourself, from scratch.

Comment: One short follow-up question. In `:h :argu`, it is mentioned: `Edit file [count] in the argument list.  When [count] is omitted the current entry is used.` What do they refer to with the `current entry` here? This is actually why I assumed that it does have some state, but now I realize that probably I misinterpreted this.

Comment: I have always understood it as "the last file that was edited that is part of the list".